# holding modal after page refreshing

Tags: javascript, django, modal-dialog

I am working in a project where I show some modals under certain conditions, after some work I realized that if I try to refresh the page while a modal is showing up, the modal vanishes.

I would like to know if there is a method that would let me render the modal when refreshing the page.

I tried this java script code:

```
// Get the modal
  var modalBtn = document.getElementById("modalBtn");

  // // Get the button that opens the modal
  // var buttonModal = document.getElementById("buttonModal");

  window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
    buttonModal.click();
    console.log("refresh")
  }

  // //hold modal
  buttonModal.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //   //show error modal
    $("#modal_error").modal()
  })
```

In the case I click on buttonModal, I can see the modal, but when I refresh it vanishes.

If I refresh the page I can see the modal for an short period of time, but it does not hold itself.

would there be a way that let me hold the modal, if its being display, inclusive after refreshing?

Luis

Comment: You could use ```sessionStorage``` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or ```localStorage``` to detect returning visitors?

Comment: You could save the current state of open modals using browser storage as well as  the URL (by replacing, not by adding a new entry). (Using the `#hash` part of the URL to open a modal is somewhat of a classic hack).  However, conceptually, that goes against what modals are meant for: modals are supposed to be pockets of page real estate (they are part of current page). When you start wanting to be able to have the modal open when pressing F5, it's a good indication that content should not be inside a modal, but it should have its own separate page.